# Tramp: SSH login does not prompt for password

Tags: tramp, passwords

I am trying to use Tramp to log into a server that has no SSH keys, just a password. Unfortunately, upon execution of my `/ssh:root@111.111.111.111:~/` command, there is no password prompt and the minibuffer says `Sending password`, and fails to login. How can I get Tramp to prompt me for a password? Or, how can I configure Tramp to log into this server that has no SSH keys and just a password?

I can SSH into the server via terminal just fine with `ssh root@111.111.111.111`, where the password prompt is:

```
root@111.111.111.111's password:
```

Unless I enter my password, there is no other output in the terminal.

---

Here is the output in my `*Messages*` buffer:

```
Tramp: Opening connection for root@111.111.111.111 using ssh...
Tramp: Sending command `exec ssh -l root  -e none 111.111.111.111'

Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell
Tramp: Sending password
Tramp: Sending command `exec ssh -l root  -e none 111.111.111.111'
Tramp: Opening connection for root@111.111.111.111 using ssh...done
Quit
```

and after setting a verbose output using `(setq tramp-verbose 10)`, here is the output into my `*debug tramp/ssh root@111.111.111.111*` buffer:

http://pastebin.com/UKJnzP66

Note that I get the same results when using `emacs -q`.

My `M-x tramp-version` is 2.2.6-24.3, running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Any help would be appreciated, or even a description of the logs. I am confused because Tramp seems to be sending some kind of default password without prompting me, even when run with `emacs -q`.

**Update**

I tried setting `tramp-password-prompt-regexp` with the following:

```
  (setq
    tramp-password-prompt-regexp
      (concat
        "^.*"
        (regexp-opt
          '("passphrase" "Passphrase"
            ;; English
            "password" "Password"
            ;; Deutsch
            "passwort" "Passwort"
            ;; Français
            "mot de passe" "Mot de passe") t)
        ".*:\0? *"))
```

which is `^.*\(Mot de passe\|Pass\(?:phrase\|wor[dt]\)\|mot de passe\|pass\(?:phrase\|wor[dt]\)\).*:^@` when evaluated with `(message tramp-password-prompt-regexp)`.

and here is the updated output from `*debug tramp/ssh root@111.111.111.111*`:

(lines 1-44)
http://pastebin.com/99w6LbyX
(lines 45-88)
http://pastebin.com/2LrDYzNk

Comment: Set verbosity a little higher and then take a look at the logs: `(setq tramp-verbose 10)`

Comment: I updated my question above. It didn't add much extra output, unfortunately. Thanks for the tip; let me know if I can do more to help.

Comment: You should also have buffer with a name like `*debug tramp*` or similar.  This should tell you a little more.  TRAMP does not write the debug messages to `*Messages*`.

Comment: @rekado thanks, I updated the `*debug tramp*` buffer output. I'm still not sure why Tramp doesn't offer a password prompt.

Comment: be sure to take a look at the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Remote-shell-setup.html#Remote-shell-setup It looks like TRAMP fails to find the remote password prompt.  Check the value of `tramp-password-prompt-regexp` and the actual password prompt on the remote.

Comment: Are you sure that the remote server permits root login over SSH?

Comment: I updated the question, where I can login with SSH over terminal and my attempts to set the `tramp-password-prompt-regexp` variable. The regex seems right, but am I missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22149/discussion-between-lucas-and-rekado).

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you could solve your problem. If not, I recommend to ask on the Tramp mailing list <tramp-devel@gnu.org>.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus Thanks for the follow up. No, I did not solve this problem. I will email them right away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, I had an incorrectly configured `~/.authinfo` that causes Tramp to automatically send a default password (which was the incorrect password). Deleting `~/.authinfo` resolved my issue.

An incorrectly configured `~/.netrc` can also cause this same issue. So make sure to check whether a `.authinfo` or `.netrc` file exists, and ensure that it is not submitting an incorrect password as the default.

@MichaelAlbinus and the Tramp-dev team helped me resolve this issue. After submitting my verbose log output to the Tramp-dev team, I received this response:

```
Tramp sends a password, but a wrong one:

> 19:58:17.561007 tramp-send-command (6) # exec ssh -l root  -e none 111.111.111.111
> 19:58:19.457169 tramp-accept-process-output (10) #
> root@111.111.111.111's password:
> 19:58:19.463921 tramp-action-password (3) # Sending password
> 19:58:21.526264 tramp-process-actions (6) #
> root@111.111.111.111's password:
> Received disconnect from 111.111.111.111: 2: Too many authentication failures for root
```

Deleting my `.authinfo` file brought back Tramp's password prompt. It was my error for not having Gnus Authinfo properly configured.

Unfortunately my complete logs are too long to attach or pastebin here, but I hope this is enough of a summary to help others out.

Answer (score 3):

If the account you're trying to log in with uses some weird fancy shell prompt, then there is a good chance that this is what makes tramp trip.

One way to test it: Log in as root, then enter

```
PS1="> "
```

(that's a normal, standard shell (ZSH, BASH, younameit) prompt, one that tramp will understand)
then switch to the user account, and launch  `emacs -q` (to make sure that your `.emacs` is not causing this mess) and try to `C-x C-f /sudo:root@localhost:/etc/hosts` and see what's what.

You can (not recommended) also customize the regexp that defines what tramps expects :

```
M-x customize-variable RET tramp-terminal-prompt-regexp
```

My approach :

1. Make sure The variable `tramp-terminal-type` is set to "dumb"

`M-x customize-variable RET  tramp-terminal-type`

2. Test that in your .*shrc and serve the correct prompt :

> ```
> case "$TERM" in
> "dumb")
>     PS1="> "
>     ;;
> xterm*|rxvt*|eterm*|screen*)
>     PS1="my fancy multi-line \n prompt > "
>     ;;
> *)
>     PS1="> "
>     ;;
> esac
> ```

Comment: I understood this could have been the problem by looking at Tramp's code, which attempts to interpret the login prompt in all the languages of the world. No way it can detect a modern prompt, and in fact a fast search led to you. However, to detect SSH, I think it could be better the more specific `if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ] ...`.